# method in JavaScript object didnt work

Tags: javascript

i write this sourse, but i dont understand why if i put `this.isExist()` function **inside** the `chat()` function (the main function), its didnt work.

but if i put `this.isExsist()` function **outside** the `this.chat` function, its works as well.

someone can explain to me why its like this?

---

***here is the source that didnt work:***

```
<a href="javascript: chat(1,111);"> new chat 1</a><br />
<a href="javascript: chat(2,222);"> new chat 2</a><br />
<a href="javascript: chat(3,333);"> new chat 3</a><br />
<a href="javascript: chat(4,444);"> new chat 4</a><br />
<a href="javascript: chat(5,555);"> new chat 5</a><br />

<div id='chatBar.1' style='float:left; position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:10px;'></div> 
<script>
function chat(id, nic) {
    this.max = 3;
    if (typeof(this.arrChat) == "undefined") {
        this.arrChat = new Array();
        this.arrChat['i'] = 0;
        this.arrChat['n'] = 0;
    }
    if (this.isExist(id) == false) {     // here i use the 'this.isExist()' function
        this.arrChat['i']++;
        this.arrChat['n']++;
        this.arrChat[this.arrChat['i']] = [id,nic];

        design = "<div id='chatBar."+(this.arrChat['n']+1)+"' style='float:right;'>nnn</div><div id='chatInfo."+this.arrChat['i']+"' style='float:right;'>info "+this.arrChat['i']+" - "+this.arrChat[this.arrChat['i']].toString()+"</div>";
        document.getElementById('chatBar.'+this.arrChat['n']).innerHTML = design;
    }


    this.isExist = function (id) {     // this function inside the 'chat()' function
        if (this.arrChat['n'] == 0) { return false; }
        for (i=1; i<=this.arrChat['i']; i++) {
            if (id == this.arrChat[i][0]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

***here is the source that works fine:***

```
<a href="javascript: chat(1,111);"> new chat 1</a><br />
<a href="javascript: chat(2,222);"> new chat 2</a><br />
<a href="javascript: chat(3,333);"> new chat 3</a><br />
<a href="javascript: chat(4,444);"> new chat 4</a><br />
<a href="javascript: chat(5,555);"> new chat 5</a><br />

<div id='chatBar.1' style='float:left; position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:10px;'></div> 
<script>
function chat(id, nic) {
    this.max = 3;
    if (typeof(this.arrChat) == "undefined") {
        this.arrChat = new Array();
        this.arrChat['i'] = 0;
        this.arrChat['n'] = 0;
    }
    if (this.isExist(id) == false) {     // here i use the 'this.isExist()' function
        this.arrChat['i']++;
        this.arrChat['n']++;
        this.arrChat[this.arrChat['i']] = [id,nic];

        design = "<div id='chatBar."+(this.arrChat['n']+1)+"' style='float:right;'>nnn</div><div id='chatInfo."+this.arrChat['i']+"' style='float:right;'>info "+this.arrChat['i']+" - "+this.arrChat[this.arrChat['i']].toString()+"</div>";
        document.getElementById('chatBar.'+this.arrChat['n']).innerHTML = design;
    }
}   

this.isExist = function (id) {     // this function outside the 'chat()' function
    for (i=1; i<=this.arrChat['i']; i++) {
        if (id == this.arrChat[i][0]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: None of your variables are local! Learn to use `var` statements

Comment: Your `chat` function is written as a constructor, it **must** be invoked as `new chat(…)`! Then, do put the method outside: `chat.prototype.isExist = function(id) {…};`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really poorly coded with global variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `"method"` before it's being defined!

Just grab it up (above the line that uses it) and should work fine.

Hope it helps

```
function chat(id, nic) {
    // ....

    if (this.isExist(id) == false) {     // At this stage, your method is not yet defined
        this.arrChat['i']++;             // It should be put above this line for example
        this.arrChat['n']++;
        this.arrChat[this.arrChat['i']] = [id,nic];

        design = "<div id='chatBar." + (this.arrChat['n'] + 1) 
               + "' style='float:right;'> nnn </div> <div id='chatInfo." 
               + this.arrChat['i'] + "' style='float:right;'> info " 
               + this.arrChat['i'] + " - " 
               + this.arrChat[this.arrChat['i']].toString() 
               + "</div>";
        document.getElementById('chatBar.' + this.arrChat['n']).innerHTML = design;
    }

    // ....
}
```

Hope it helps